# In c# resharper suggested "conditional access", what does null give me?

Tags: c#

I use Resharper to help with language features and I have a DateTime field that is nullable.  Resharper suggested this syntax:

```
 TodayDate = paidDate?.ToString("d"),
```

It looks like a standard expresson but I don't get one question mark.  two question marks I get and colon I get.

An explanation would be appreciated.  whathappens when paidDate is null?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/900017/Null-Propagation-Operator-A-New-Feature-of-Csharp

Comment: Its a C#6 feature, it wouldn't be suggested in C#5, basically it returns null if `paidDate` is null, otherwise it runs the `.ToString` on it. Its an inline check for null, otherwise in C#5 you have to check for `paidDate` having a value before you can call `.ToString` on it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`?.` is a new feature introduced in C# and it's called [Null-conditional Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx). It evaluates method call only when `paidDate` is not null, and returns `null` instead.

It's pretty much equivalent to

```
TodayDate = paidDate == null ? null : paidDate.ToString("d");
```

If you try calling a method that returns value type after `?.` it will make the whole thing return `Nullable<T>` of that value type, e.g.

```
var myValue = paidDate?.Day;
```

would make `myValue` be typed as `Nullable<int>`.